# I am trying to get 6 separate input numbers from the user for my program using one textbox

Tags: vb6

I have been trying to use a textbox in VB6 to acquire 6 different random numbers chosen by the user to use in part of my program. I have tried many different approaches in different areas of the code. Best I have gotten so far is in the keypress section. I set up an array to store the 6 entries buy fail to be able to get past storing one number in the first element. I'm using a for next loop to cycle through the elements but the textbox.setfocus will not work properly in the loop. I clear the box then setfocus after I assign the number to an element in the array. The only other way I'm thinking this would work is to hide the single box and show 6 hidden ones and then they can tab or I can hide each one again as they fill up.
Here's a snip of that code so one should get an idea what I'm trying to do here.

```
Private Sub Inbox_Keypress(KeyAscii As Integer)

Select Case KeyAscii                            ' Determine keypress

    Case vbKey0 To vbKey9                       'Only the numbers
    Case vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete     ' Accept these keys
    Case vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight                  ' Arrow keys
    Case 13                                     ' Enter
        If GenOpt(5).Value = True Then
            For c = 1 To 6
                Gen6_user(c) = Inbox.Text
                'Select Case KeyAscii
                '    Case 13

                    Talkbox.Caption = "Please enter the next user number for Generator 6"
                'Case Else
                '   MsgBox Msg, style, title
                'End Select
                If c = 6 Then Exit For

                Do
                Inbox.Text = ""
                Inbox.SetFocus
                Loop Until KeyAscii = 13
            Next

            For c = 1 To 6
                Msg6.Print Gen6_user(c)
            Next
        Else

            User_number = Inbox.Text           ' Assign any final value to User_number variabl)
            Generate.SetFocus
            'Generate_Click                          ' Call generate function
        End If
```

Any help would be appreciated

Journey

Comment: why not 6 textboxes on a dialog so the user can see what they have already added?

Answer (score 0):

I am at work and I don't have VB6 handy here... but, this should work (maybe with a few little tweaks, I am sure you can figure those out):

```
Dim x As Integer = 1
Dim myArray(6) As Integer

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        myArray(x) = TextBox1.Text
        x = x + 1
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End If

    If x = 6 Then
        Debug.Print("Here you check your numbers?")
    End If
End Sub
```